# iOS App built from Expo does not open on device

Tags: ios, expo

- command used to build .ipa `exp build:ios`
- expo handled the certificates (distribution and push notification)
- device tested on AWS Device farm: iPhone 5, iOS: 10.3.2

Syslog from the device farm

> Jan 16 12:34:15 9902472814 SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : Unable
>   to register for exec notifications: No such process Jan 16 12:34:15
>   9902472814 SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[57] : Unable to get short BSD
>   proc info for 344: No such process Jan 16 12:34:15 9902472814
>   SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[57] : Unable to get proc info for 344:
>   No such process Jan 16 12:34:15 9902472814 SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[57]
>   : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 344:
>   (os/kern) failure (0x5) Jan 16 12:34:15 9902472814
>   SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[57] : Unable to get short BSD proc info
>   for 344: No such process Jan 16 12:34:15 9902472814
>   SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : Unable to obtain a process handle
>   for
>
> Aborting with
>   error: Error Domain=BSTransactionError Code=3 "Transaction aborted.
>   (parent transaction)"
>   UserInfo={transaction=, precipitating-error=Error Domain=BSTransactionError
>   Code=1 "Transaction failed. Child transaction failed:
>    (child transaction)"
>   UserInfo={transaction=, precipitating-error=Error Domain=BSTransactionError
>   Code=1 "Transaction failed. no client provider for client with
>   bundleID com.xxxxxxx.mobileapp (scene update failed)"
>   UserInfo={transaction=,
>   error-reason=scene update failed, error-description=no client provider
>   for client with bundleID com.xxxxxxx.mobileapp,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Transaction failed. no client provider for
>   client with bundleID com.xxxxxxx.mobileapp (scene update failed)},
>   error-reason=child transaction, error-description=Child transaction
>   failed: : numberOfClients
>   GyroOnly:, 3AxisDynamicGyro:, 6Axis:,
>   6AxisThrottledGyro:, 9Axis:,
>   9AxisWithNorthReference:

App gets installed but doesn’t open. Any leads would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I had posted the question on Expo forum: https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-app-does-not-open-on-device/6495/10. It has got to do with provisioning the binary specifically for AWS device farm.

Comment: What kind of test are you running? XC TEST UI or appium?

Comment: I am running appium tests.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the other logs like appium server output and the appium java output?  

Also, does this work on a local physical device?  It might be something with device farm.